# Convert csv data to nested json format

Tags: python, json, loops, nested

I have a csv data as:

> dataf = pd.DataFrame{'title':['tit1', 'tit1', 'tit2' 'tit2','tit3'],
> 'context':['con1', 'con1', 'con2', 'con2', 'con3'],
> 'answers':['text1', 'text2', 'text3', 'text4', 'text5'],
> 'question':['que1', 'que2', 'que3', 'que4', 'que5'], 'id':['DDA',
> 'SAV', 'AFS', 'ML', 'MLI']}

I want to convert it into nested json format as below using python

```
[
  {
    "title": "tit1",
    "paragraph": [
      {
        "context": "con1",
        "qas": [
          {
            "answers": "text1",
            "question": "que1",
            "id": "DDA"
          },
          {
            "answers": "text2",
            "question": "que2",
            "id": "SAV"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "title": "tit2",
    "paragraph": [
      {
        "context": "con2",
        "qas": [
          {
            "answers": "text3",
            "question": "que3",
            "id": "AFS"
          },
          {
            "answers": "text4",
            "question": "que4",
            "id": "ML"
          }

        ],
        "context": "con3",
        "qas": [
          {
            "answers": "text5",
            "question": "que5",
            "id": "MLI"
          }
        ]

      }
    ]
  },
]
```

and it continues for various other data

Comment: Your expected output doesn't match the input in any reasonable way. Please show your attempt(s) and more logical input/output.

Comment: Show your actual desired output based on the sample input you've provided. Do not just describe what you want; the actual output would be clearer than your description.

Comment: Please see, have updated the output

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you?

```
df = []
cont = 0;
for index, row in dataf.iterrows():
    if cont == 0:
        cont +=1
        continue
    dict = {}
    list = []
    item = {}
    qas = {}
    qas['answers']  = row[2]
    qas['question']  = row[3]
    qas['id']  = row[4]
    item['context'] = row[1]
    item['qas'] = []
    item['qas'].append(qas)
    dict[dataf[0][0]] = row[0]
    dict['paragraph'] = []
    dict['paragraph'].append(item)
    #print(dict)
    df.append(dict)

print(df)
```

Output:

```
[{'title': 'tit1', 'paragraph': [{'context': 'con1', 'qas': [{'answers': 'text1', 'question': 'que1', 'id': 'DDA'}]}]}, {'title': 'tit1', 'paragraph': [{'context': 'con1', 'qas': [{'answers': 'text2', 'question': 'que2', 'id': 'SAV'}]}]}, {'title': 'tit2', 'paragraph': [{'context': 'con2', 'qas': [{'answers': 'text3', 'question': 'que3', 'id': 'AFS'}]}]}, {'title': 'tit2', 'paragraph': [{'context': 'con2', 'qas': [{'answers': 'text4', 'question': 'que4', 'id': 'ML'}]}]}]
```

Comment: it was coming as expected but not in nested format, have updated code and output please see, need to do some grouping based on same title and context..